# Yii2 - Multiple Dropzone Widget doesn't work

Tags: yii, yii2, dropzone.js

I'm working with Yii2 to develop an intranet portal.

I have to put multiple widget in same page but it doesn't work.

Give me this error

```
Dropzone already attached.
```

And my code is

```
...
 <?= \kato\DropZone::widget([
        'id' => 'dzImages',
        'dropzoneContainer' => 'dzImages',
       'options' => [           
           'url' => 'index.php?r=orders/upload&uid='.$model->ref,
           'maxFilesize' => '10',
           'acceptedFiles' => "image/*",
       ],
    ]); ?>
    </p>

        <p>
    <?php echo \kato\DropZone::widget([
        'id' => 'dzPDF',
        'dropzoneContainer' => 'dzPDF',
       'options' => [           
           'url' => 'index.php?r=orders/uploadpdf&uid='.$model->ref,
           'maxFilesize' => '10',
           'acceptedFiles' => ".pdf",
       ],
    ]); 
    ?>
    </p>
...
```

How can i resolve it?

Comment: what is \kato\DropZone? where do you get that from? The implementation of the widget seems essential for understanding the issue.

Comment: I've got it from https://github.com/perminder-klair/yii2-dropzone

Comment: [SOLVED] With a clean installation of \kato\DropZone plugin and without any personalization (no source code changes and without JS changes like `Dropzone.options.myDropzone(){...}` ) all works fine. My tips for all is to edit just the PHP part in your YII2 source, set unique `'id', 'dropzoneContainer',  'previewsContainer'` for each DropZone widget. Thx to all

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [code of the widget](https://github.com/perminder-klair/yii2-dropzone/blob/41e8145d940cc9955011138a9f16ad80e9831423/DropZone.php#L58-L63), the 'id' parameter seems to be used differently than one would expect, instead you should probably set `previewsContainer` property too.

The ID parameter seems to be used as a JavaScript variable here:

https://github.com/perminder-klair/yii2-dropzone/blob/41e8145d940cc9955011138a9f16ad80e9831423/DropZone.php#L75